# Ignore npm native addon compilation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a way to do an `npm install` that downloads dependencies but then it does not try to compile native addons?

Long story: My company has a build server running on Windows (can't change that) and it's getting complicated to compile some native addons there. This application is eventually deployed to Linux, so an `npm rebuild` is necessary anyways. Also, I can't do the `npm install` on the destination servers because they don't have access to the registry.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script (for Windows a JS file, for every other platform a shell script) that does nothing and is used instead of the normal node-gyp.

After that use

```
npm config set node_gyp <script_with_full_path>
```

to force npm to use your script instead of the normal node-gyp and by that skip the compile step.

Please note that requiring the module that used gyp may fail because the built file is now missing.

Hope this helps.